# Why glBufferSubData for element buffer must be called outside of glBindVertexArray?

Tags: opengl, jogl

I'm trying to replace contents of element buffer in this hello world example https://github.com/jvm-graphics-labs/hello-triangle/blob/master/src/main/java/gl4/HelloTriangleSimple.java and I managed to do it with some minor changes by using `glBufferSubData`, but I'm curious about one peculiarity - in my display method I have to call `glBufferSubData` before I call `glBindVertexArray`:

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferName.get(Buffer.ELEMENT));
elementBuffer.rewind();
elementBuffer.put(elementData).rewind();
gl.glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, elementBuffer.capacity() * Short.BYTES, elementBuffer);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
gl.glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayName.get(0));
```

If I do it after `glBindVertexArray`, I'm getting only black window. The strange thing is that `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` *can* be updated after `glBindVertexArray`. What is the difference between vertex buffer and element buffer behind this observation?

Comment: The name of the element array buffer object is stored in the vertex array objects state vector. It the VAO is bound and you do `gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)` then the name of the element buffer object is replaced by 0 and the reference to elements is borken. This causes that `gl.drawElements` won't work any more for the VAO.

Comment: @Rabbid76 This is the answer. If you copy it as a real answer, I will mark it as such. If you don't, I'll copy it myself. I have tried it and also what you say is pretty obvious now, but as a begginer I couldn't see the connection. However I'm still a bit puzzled about the difference between buffers. If I can bind 0 as GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and the drawing still works, does that mean that it's _not_ referenced from VAO?

Comment: The VAO stores the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` type buffer binding. But it doesn't with `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` types, which are stored by `glVertexAttribPointer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` object is stored in the vertex array objects state vector.

If a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) is bound 
 the an element buffer can be attached to it by

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferName.get(Buffer.ELEMENT));
```

But if you do

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

then the name of the element buffer object is replaced by 0 and the reference to the elements is broken. This causes that `gl.drawElements` won't work any more for the this VAO, because it doesn't refer to any index list.

---

Further note, there is always a vertex array object. The vertex array object 0 is the default vertex array object which is only valid when you use a compatibility profile context (not core).

This means that

```
gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferName.get(Buffer.ELEMENT));
```

will associate a element buffer to the default vertex array object (0). This is perfectly valid in compatibility profile context.

---

See the [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 10.3.1 Vertex Array Objects; page 393](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf):

> The name space for vertex array objects is the unsigned integers, **with zero
>   reserved by the GL to represent the default vertex array object.**
>   The command
>
> ```
> void GenVertexArrays( sizei n, uint *arrays );
> ```
>
> returns n previous unused vertex array object names in arrays.
>
> ...
>
> A vertex array object is created by binding a name returned by `GenVertexArray` with the command
>
> ```
> void BindVertexArray( uint array );
> ```
>
> `array` is the vertex array object name. The resulting vertex array object is a new state vector, comprising all the state and with the same initial values listed in tables 23.3 and 23.4.
>   `BindVertexArray` may also be used to bind an existing vertex array object. If the bind is successful no change is made to the state of the bound vertex array object, and any previous binding is broken.
>
> Table 23.4, Vertex Array Object State
>   **`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`**, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_BINDING`, `VERTEX_ATTRIB_RELATIVE_OFFSET`, `VERTEX_BINDING_OFFSET`, `VERTEX_BINDING_STRIDE`, `VERTEX_BINDING_DIVISOR`, `VERTEX_BINDING_BUFFER`.